# hasClass method is not returning boolean result

Tags: css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

[image]The below code is not returning boolean as return type. Instead it is returned as a function

```
var resAbnormal = await Selector(resultCard.find('.dbm-lab-result-card-container').nth(y).find('.titlerow')).hasClass('abnormal');
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Which div would you like to select? the one having class="value abnormal") and no child?

Comment: Please describe your issue in more detail and provide a test code and a full test page here, which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace this selector you are using,

```
var resAbnormal = await Selector(resultCard.find('.dbm-lab-result-card-container').nth(y).find('.titlerow')).hasClass('abnormal');
```

with the next suggestion

```
var resAbnormal = Selector("div.dbm-lab-result-card-container div.abnormal");
```

What this suggestion of selector does is to return the first match from your DOM, even if you have several DOM elements matching this Selector:

```
... <div class="dbm-lab-result-card-container">
    ...
    <div class="whatever abnormal whatever">    <-- you will select this one
    <div class="whatever abnormal whatever">
    ...
```

If you are using `await`, like you do now,

```
var resAbnormal = await Selector("div.dbm-lab-result-card-container div.abnormal");
```

then Testcafe will return to you all the DOM elements matching that selector, and most likely you'll have returned a function/list and then you have to use 
`resAbnormal.nth[x]` to find the one you want.

Furthermore, if you wait for a boolean result, then what you should use one of the next assertions:

```
await t.expect(resAbnormal.exists).ok();
// or
await t.expect(resAbnormal.exists).eql(true);
```

Hope this helps.